# How to make a whole li element clickable to toggle checkmark?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a list where each line has name on the left and a checkmark on the right, I want to be able to just click on the whole element to toggle the checkbox without using jquery.

```
<div class="list-checkbox list-group list-button mx-auto mt-2">
  <button class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <span>Option 1</span>
      <label class="checkboxCustom my-auto">
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
   </button>
 </div>
```

This is my script

```
  document.getElementbyClassName('div.list-checkbox button').click(function() {
    var $cb = $(this).find(":checkbox");
    if (!$cb.getAttribute("checked")) {
      $cb.setAttribute("checked", true);
    } else {
      $cb.setAttribute("checked", false);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Get rid of the `button` element - it's invalid where you have it anyway. Make the `label` fit all content within the `li` and you get this behaviour for free without any JS

Comment: You can put the whole line into the label element, and provide a for attribute for the label, so it will toggle the checkbox

Comment: Does this have to be done via JS? As Rory McCrossan points out, there is no need for JS to get this done. As far as I can see from your example there is no special need to do this via JS.

Comment: I turned the button into a label and it works after some css tweak, but now if I click a couple of time it highlights the text in the label, (and the cursor it's not a hand anymore), that's why I used button, why is it not valid?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are using JQuery so I just added some small changes:

```js
  $('div.list-checkbox').on('click',function() {
    var $cb = $(this).find("checkbox");
    if (!$cb.attr("checked")) {
      $cb.attr("checked", true);
    } else {
      $cb.attr("checked", false);
    }
  });
```

I hope it helped.

Comment: I'm using jquery because of bootstrap but I'd like to convert it to plain javascript

Comment: Not a problem. It just seems like you mixed the APIs when you used `document.getElementByClassName('div.list-checkbox button')`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```html
<label><input type="checkbox">List value 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox">List value 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox">List value 3</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to do just that:

1. Add an id attribute to the `checkbox` `input` element, e.g. `id="check1"`
2. Put all the markup that should respond to the click in a label element and add a `for` attribute with `id` value in 1 above e.g. `for="check1"`

```html
<div class="list-checkbox list-group list-button mx-auto mt-2">
  <button class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <label for="check1">
      <span>Option 1</span>
      <label class="checkboxCustom my-auto">
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="check1">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
      </label>
   </button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.acc {
  position: relative;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #4a19ff;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-family: "Spicy Rice", cursive;
}
label::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10px;
  border-left: 8px solid black;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ h2 label::before {
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top: 8px solid black;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

p {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 30px;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease;
  font-family: "Habibi", serif;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ h2 ~ p {
  max-height: 80px;
}

body {
  background: #fffefa;
}
```

```html
<div class="acc">
        <input type="checkbox" id="faq-1">
        <h2><label for="faq-1">How much?</label></h2>
        <p>She said for $300 she'll do it.</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="acc">
        <input type="checkbox" id="faq-2">
        <h2><label for="faq-2">How many cans must I stack up?</label></h2>
        <p>As many as you need to wash you out from my mind and out of my consciousness.</p>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The right way to make an HTML element clickable is to wrap it in a <label> element